# error in basic ci implementation in gitlab fatal: couldn't find remote ref

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I setup fresh gitlab docker , then set up a runner docker with docer executer based on  microsoft/dotnet:latest
then I added simple project to gitlab just a dotnet core hello world
then I create a ci file as below:

```
image:  microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - build


variables:
  project: "ConsoleApp"

before_script:
  - "dotnet restore"

build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    build_path: "$ConsoleApp"
  script:
    - "cd $build_path"
    - "dotnet build"
```

then in pipleline I get this output:

```
Preparing environment
 Running on runner-vtysysr-project-2-concurrent-0 via e189cc9d1c60...
Getting source from Git repository
00:07
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/gitlabcitest/.git/
 fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/pipelines/18
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:06
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I searched error but all asnwers are about projects which have branches, but I dont have any branch, just a simple hello world project.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm working from Gitlab's own README for CI. I've opened a bounty.

Comment: Hi, my issue was in ssh config in runner docker, after add ssh key to docker issue solved

Comment: Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @alikamrani could you please elaborate a bit more on what your issue was and how you were able to resolve it

Answer (score 4):

The [OP ali-kamrani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2907555/ali-kamrani) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791907/error-in-basic-ci-implementation-in-gitlab-fatal-couldnt-find-remote-ref?noredirect=1#comment116072648_61791907):

> my issue was in ssh `config` in runner docker: after [adding the ssh key to docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/), the issue is solved.

---

Other avenues (for other users) if this is similar to [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 36123](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/36123)

> We were using `git push --mirror` to mirror some projects from a different repository regularly.
> As it turns out, it also deletes unknown branches, i.e. `pipelines/XXXX` and `merge/XXXX`.
>
> We are now pushing & deleting every branch explicitly and ignoring all `pipelines/XXXX` and `merge/XXXX` ones.
> Afterwards the error didn't occur again.

I understand you don't have many branches, but the issue here is not with your local branches.
It is with a push operation, initiated locally, *pruning* remote branches which does not exist locally.

> Basically, pipelines are depending on a pipeline specific ref `refs/pipelines/*` and it has to exist when the pipeline is running.
> So if `git push --mirror` deletes these refs, you might encounter the job failure.

The same issue illustrates a similar scenario:

> In our setup, we are using a system hook to mirror our GitLab repositories into another location closer to where our GitLab Runner instances are.
> This has worked fine for a long time.
>
> However, now that GitLab is dependent on the `refs/pipelines/<pipeline ID>` ref existing, all of our runners fail.
>
> The problem is that the `refs/pipelines/<pipeline ID>` ref gets created behind the scenes and there is no system hook that gets invoked (so we don't know about the new ref that needs to be mirrored).
> The built-in Repository Mirroring feature isn't very suitable for us because it must be configured for each repository; with System Hooks, we can automatically mirror all of our repositories.

Comment: Note: this can come from the gitlab-ci.yml. For instance, this one (https://git.legeox.net/capslock/signal-gcm-less/-/commit/9fd1aaa347427cbbc1e3e4e09b3635b3c394c6b4) works, while its previous version (in red) triggered the same error: https://git.legeox.net/capslock/signal-gcm-less/-/jobs/692

Comment: It's unclear to me what "my issue was in ssh config in runner docker: after adding the ssh key to docker, the issue is solved." means or how to do it

Comment: @karobar I suspect the config file was referencing a specific path/filename for the ssh key, and that key was not present with that name.

Comment: how to add the keys for docker can be found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/

Comment: @FelixOuttaSpace Thank you. I have edited the answer to reference your link.